# Spring - how to inject concrete interface implementation?

Tags: java, spring, service, dependency-injection, autowired

I need to inject by @Autowired concrete implementation of a service class.

Service interface:

```
public interface PostService {
...
}
```

Implementation:

```
@Service("postServiceImpl")
public class PostServiceImpl implements PostService {
...
}
```

Methods in the service are with @ Transactional annotation

And now I want to inject postServiceImpl to my controller - because I need to use one method from the implementation, that is not in the interface:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("postServiceImpl")
private PostServiceImpl postService;
```

I get **NoSuchBeanDefinitionException** with the following message:

> No qualifying bean of type [ (...) .PostServiceImpl] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency.

when I change the field in my controller to:

```
private PostService postService
```

it works, but I can't use a specific method from PostServiceImpl.

Comment: Then add it to the interface. What's the point of declaring interfaces if you inject the concrete type?

Comment: Have you got some aspects applied to that bean? Or proxies interface-based?

Comment: @fcracker79 I think I have, because methods in the service are with  @ Transactional annotation.

Comment: Injecting concrete implementations defies the whole objective of IoC.

Comment: @JBNizet I have a specific setter for a field, that is only in the implementation - I need to use this setter in integration tests. I think there is no other solution.

Comment: What about '<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"/>'?

Comment: Sure there is: declare the setter in the interface. Or declare it in another interface that your bean also implements. Or don't use interfaces at all, since you're ready to use the concrete class directly anyway.

Comment: Using setters for bare fields in service implementations is a definite code smell.  Your service class has a dependency and rather than injecting it, you are setting it explicitly.  Why don't you auto-wire that field as well?  If you have to do it just in an integration test, use Spring Profiles to wire different values during actual runs and during runs.  Use the framework to the fullest.

Comment: @JBNizet I reconsidered your idea and decided to move setter to the interface, definitely best and clean option. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since your methods are annotated `@Transactional`, spring will create proxy at runtime, to inject transaction management code. By default Spring uses *JDK Dynamic Proxy* for proxying mechanism, which proxies based on interfaces.

So, in this case, spring creates another class which implements `PostService` interface, and creates bean of that class. Definitely that cannot be autowired to `PostServiceImpl`, as those are siblings. However, if you really want to autowire on class, you can force spring to use *CGLib* proxy instead, which proxies using subclassing. That you can do by setting `proxyTargetClass=true` in your `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation, if you're using Java based config.