# Spring Injecting implementation instead of interface

Tags: spring

Here my class structure  :

```
public interface CertificatService
{
}
```

The only one implementation

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CertificatServiceImpl extends GestionCertificat implements CertificatService
{
}
```

And the injection :

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ConnexionEbicsServiceImpl extends GestionConnexion implements ConnexionEbicsService
{
@Inject
private CertificatServiceImpl certificatService;
}
```

}

```
Injection the implementation causes injection failure :

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connexionEbicsServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.tess2i.service.impl.CertificatServiceImpl com.tess2i.service.impl.ConnexionEbicsServiceImpl.certificatService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.tess2i.service.impl.CertificatServiceImpl] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
```

But if I inject the interface, it works :

```
 @Service
    @Transactional
    public class ConnexionEbicsServiceImpl extends GestionConnexion implements ConnexionEbicsService
    {
    @Inject
    private CertificatService certificatService;
    }

}
```

But I need to inject the implementation so to benefit methods inherited from `GestionCertificat`

Can you help me to autowired the implementation. I understand that the real type is a proxy and not the implementation class `CertificatServiceImpl` as I would like. But what is the solution so ?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring - how to inject concrete interface implementation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28925311/spring-how-to-inject-concrete-interface-implementation)

Comment: Why bother with an interface if you don't want to use it to program against. Of course you could use `proxy-target-class=true` on your configuration but that basically defeats the purpose of having an interface in the first place. IMHO the fact that you need specific methods instead of those on the interface is basically a flaw in your design.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect.

Just using proxy via CGLIB it is OK setting proxyTargetClass = true :

@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)

Thanks for the answer here : [Spring - how to inject concrete interface implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28925311/spring-how-to-inject-concrete-interface-implementation)